# Power level limits on saves: Which interpretation is correct?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds, mutants-and-masterminds-2e

This question has been confusing me, since the relevant text on power levels says

> Fortitude, Reflex, and Will Saves: Your hero’s total Fortitude, Reflex,
>   and Will save modifiers cannot exceed the campaign’s power level +5.

I originally read this to mean that the three saves totaled together could not exceed the power level plus 5 (so a fortitude of +4, reflex of +6, and will of +5 would be exactly enough for a PL 10 game), but the character archetypes written at said power level include saves of Fort +10, Ref +8, Will +10; which leads me to think that this rule means each individual save could go no higher than +15 in a PL 10 game.  **Which interpretation is correct?  The first, the second, or some other one I haven't thought of?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each save cannot go higher than PL+5. So a PL 10 character could be sporting Will +15, Reflex +15, and Fortitude +15.

Frankly, though, that level of saves is pretty ridiculous. Some people on The Atomic Think Tank ran the stats on the published characters from Green Ronin and the average was approximately PL-2 for the three exotic saves. Many of the PbP games there asked players to stick with that ratio. For balanced saves, it gives you an almost 50% chance of no effect, and a fairly low chance of a severe outcode.